# react country flag in react with typescript project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm

Hey I am recently working with react and typescript together and I wanted to have some country logos, I installed this package which seems to be the most popular one for reactjs, the package called react country flag, and I cannot use it maybe with ts? is that the case?
my error is the one in the image below.

[image]

Comment: and the error message tells you exactly what you need to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package does not come with typescript types, do this in the terminal. This will try to download the types for that package if they exist

```
npm i --save-dev @types/react-country-flag
```

If it still doesn't exist, add

//@ts-ignore above the import line, like this:

```
//@ts-ignore
import ReactCountryFlag from "react-country-flag"
```

That will ignore the error you are having